# GROUP BY issue with multiple nested SELECT statements

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, syntax-error

I am having a syntax error pop-up every time I run my query.

The error is:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Below is my code:

```
    SELECT
    d.*, >>>>SUM(L.ALLOCATED_QTY)<<<<
FROM
    alc_item_loc l
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT
            c.* 
        FROM
            store s,
            (   
                SELECT
                    a.*,
                    b.location AS store_number
                FROM
                    fdt_map_cluster_location b,
                    (   
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            ss.alloc_cluster_id,
                            ss.alloc_cluster_name,
                            ss.worksheet_id,
                            ss.sku
                        FROM
                            fdt_maptool_sas_data ss
                        WHERE
                            ss.sku IN (
                                1099866,
                                1099896,
                                1000898,
                                1000960,
                                1000988
                            )   
                            AND ss.order_no IS NOT NULL
                                AND alloc_cluster_name NOT LIKE '%DC Cluster%'
                        GROUP BY
                            ss.alloc_cluster_id,
                            ss.alloc_cluster_name,
                            ss.worksheet_id,
                            ss.sku
                    ) a 
                WHERE
                    b.cluster_id = a.alloc_cluster_id
                    AND b.location_type = 'S' 
            ) c 
        WHERE
            s.store = c.store_number
            AND s.store_close_date IS NULL
                AND s.district NOT IN (
                997,
                998,
                999 
            )   
                    AND s.store_open_date <= SYSDATE
    ) d ON l.item_id = d.sku
           AND l.location_id = d.store_number
    >>>GROUP BY xxxx <<<<<
```

As you can see, the error is caused because I have an aggregate function (sum) and it needs to be grouped.

My problem is I do not know if I need to group everything in ( D.*) or what?

If I do need to group EVERYTHING in (D.*) then how do I do that properly?

I know that this is improper syntax but for example this is what I want to do:

```
GROUP BY D.*
```

But I am not sure how to group this???

Any help is appreciated!

PS: the ">>> <<<" are there only to show where my error lies.

Comment: Yes, syntax wise you need to include the data field in the `select` in the `group by`.  Run the query without the `sum` and `group by` to see the data field names returned.

Comment: @kc2018 Thank you so much! I am still working on my debugging procedures. This was a good little trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to group inside a subquery:

```
SELECT
    d.*, l._sum
FROM
    alc_item_loc l
    RIGHT JOIN (
        select l.item_id, l.location_id, SUM(L.ALLOCATED_QTY) _sum from (
            SELECT
                c.* 
                ....
                ....
                ....
                        AND s.store_open_date <= SYSDATE
        )l
        group by  l.item_id, l.location_id
    ) d ON l.item_id = d.sku
           AND l.location_id = d.store_number
```